# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create event with null entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, persist, modelattribute

I trying persist this entity:

```
@Entity
public class Cliente extends Model {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Usuario usuario;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private org.loja.model.cesta.Cesta cesta;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderColumn
  private List<org.loja.model.pedido.Pedido> pedidos;

  public Cliente() {
    this.usuario = new Usuario();
    this.cesta = null;
    this.pedidos = null;
  }
}
```

with this form:

```
<form class="form-signin" id="form" method="post" th:action="@{/register}">
    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario.username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="usuario.password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario.firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>

    <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Sobrenome</label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario.lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Sobrenome" required>

    <label for="email" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="usuario.email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
</form>
```

I also tried this:

```
<form class="form-signin" id="form" method="post" th:object="${command}" th:action="@{/register}">
    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{usuario.username}" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" th:field="*{usuario.password}" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

    <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{usuario.firstName}" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required>

    <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Sobrenome</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{usuario.lastName}" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Sobrenome" required>

    <label for="email" class="sr-only">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" th:field="*{usuario.email}" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
</form>
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create event with null entity
```

when I try submit the data.

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String formRegister(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("command", new Cliente());
  return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void doRegister(@ModelAttribute("cliente") Cliente object) throws Exception {
  home.register(object);
}
```

Anyone can give a hint of what's wrong here?

Comment: The error indicates that object passed to saveorUpdate is nul, have you verified in the rest call the object is not null?

Comment: I check in the browser developer tool, tab network, all the parameters are there. It is in the controller that the object is null when I try print it.